# Render dynamic props for each slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
export default defineComponent(
{
    props: ["doDisabled"],
    mounted()
    {
        this.$slots.default().forEach((vnode) => 
        {
            vnode.props[":disabled"] = this.doDisabled;
        });
    }
});
```

I want to make each slot within my component to be dynamicly disabled based on dynamic props `doDisabled`

Code above doesnt work. How I can make it work?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the colon symbol in front of `disabled` ?

Comment: Yes, it just adds disabled doesnt take in cosnideration of reactivity state of doDisabled

Comment: What happens if you reference `default` as a property rather than a function and if you use `vnode.disabled` directly ?